# Save my tomato plant from broken tip with flowers

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes, transplanting

My tomato plant fell off my deck yesterday due to higher wind.  The top of the tomato plant broke. It was the only place the plant was flowering.  Is there a way to save the plant or maybe plant the broken part? I realize there are other issues, I need to get a bigger pot, and maybe keep it out of the sun a bit more.  We have had exceptionally hot weather in the PNW lately.

Here are some pictures of my tomato plant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is only my first year vegetable gardening, but if I've learned anything it's that tomato plants are pretty resilient to damage. They also need large pots. What I would do in your boat is first, get a much bigger pot. Then prune off that broken top part, down to the part above where that little offshoot is coming out. Once you've got some soil in your new much bigger pot, prune off the very bottom branches and bury most of that stem in the soil. It will grow more roots that way. Once you do that, if it's happy, it should start growing healthier looking leaves and eventually more blossoms.

Comment: Also, if you want to try to salvage the top part, you could try sticking the bottom of it in rooting hormone, cutting off the very bottom set of leaves on the part you cut off, and then put that in a separate large pot of soil to grow new roots. A more experienced gardener might have a different idea, but I've done stuff like this with my container tomatoes and they're hanging in there.

Comment: awesome! Thank you! I will do both of these :)